# Doing hotfix in GIT

Tags: git

If I'm currently working on a new feature branch called “my-new-feature-branch” with un-committed changes and need to fix something on master (hotfix) what commands should I use to do the hotfix starting on the “my-new-feature-branch”? *

Answer (score 3):

You can stash uncommitted changes in my-new-feature branch with

```
$ git stash
```

Switch to master branch

```
$ git checkout master
```

Make your hotfix changes, commit them. Then switch back to my-new-feature branch

```
$ git checkout my-new-feature
```

And unstash code changes you made before

```
$ git stash pop
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative:

```
git add -A
git commit -m "unfinished work"
git checkout master
....
git checkout my-new-feature
git reset HEAD~1
```